# Does nuget create separate packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am still confused about how nuget works. I git clone a C# .sln project and from console, and I ran this nuget command:

```
nuget restore my_project.sln
```

it came to my attention that it generates two packages containing all dependencies required by my_project.

One package is located under **my_project/src/packages**, the other **c:/users/my_user_name/.nuget/packages**. While the file structures are a little different the DLL files in both packages are identical.

That confused me. Why two packages are generated by default? Where exactly does Visual studio look up for the project's dependencies?

More important, which config file should I update in order to only keep a copy of the dependencies and how can I specify the location in my file system for the packages?

Comment: Hi, please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders and the global-packages folder is where NuGet installs any downloaded package. Each package is fully expanded into a subfolder that matches the package identifier and version number. Projects using the PackageReference format always use packages directly from this folder. When using the packages.config, packages are installed to the global-packages folder, then copied into the project's packagesfolder.

Comment: When package restore, if a package is not already installed, NuGet first attempts to retrieve it from the above cache. If the package is not in the cache, NuGet then attempts to download the package from all enabled sources. For more detail info, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of NuGet support [package references in project files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

This format will restore packages on demand, using your %USERPROFILE%.nuget folder as a cache.  And your solution folder won't be "polluted" by a packages folder with binaries that you probably don't want to commit to source control.

VS2017 allows you to select "PackageReferences" or the older "Packages.Config" format when you create new projects (Tools/Options/NuGetPackageManager/General).

You probably have some projects in your solution that use the older "Packages.config" format, which stores in the `packages` folder in the solution directory, and newer "PackageReferences" format.

To convert the older projects to the new format, I believe you need to remove all packages from the project, then add them back again.  They will be added using the default format you selected, with a prompt for confirmation if you selected "Allow format selection on first package install".